# How To send Multiple Mime Type In GoogleDrive Fetch Request

Tags: ios

In this it Is taking the last so How Can i Send following in one

```
     GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList query];
     query.q = @"mimeType = 'application/zip'";
     query.q = @"mimeType = 'image/png'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `or` to have multiple mime types in a single `GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList`

`query.q = @"(mimeType = 'audio/mp3' or mimeType = 'audio/mpeg3')";`

Comment: Thanks 

Muhammad Abdul Subhan

Comment: No problem @VikasKumar :) Don't forget to accept the answer